# Is it possible to create a button , on click makes user login without entering to login page

Tags: c#, php, mysql

Im making a c# application, User have to login into the application.

After Login there is going to be  a button which opens a website written in php.

is there anyway, when the users click's button the website that is going to open should be already logged in, and yes c# application and website both share same sql.

Here is a idea I got but don't know how to make it work because I have poor php skill.

i read it some where, but i don't know wether it works or not :

`http://bf3.in/?login=username = Juno.... password = *****`

if it possible like this i can make it work in c# button

```
"http://bf3.in/?login=username = "'+variable1+'".... password = "'+variable1+'""
```

Comment: You shouldn't put login credentials in GET variables. In fact, your user's passwords should be hashed in your database so that wouldn't be possible anyway

Comment: It is possible. Just like that but I recommend encrypting your passwords and perform a post. Better yet, do token-based authentication like OAuth 2.0 After posting, the site should redirect you to the home page.

Comment: @Ephraim i am using hash, it was just an example code showing to you,
will it work using a link like that above ? if so how would i get a link like one

Comment: @junopro the link should be created by the site developer. I'm not  a PHP expert but in ASP.NET MVC this would be a simple action that **signs you in** and redirects you to the home page.

Comment: I have the website script with me and i too know the mysql query,
does it help ?

Answer (score -1):

You need to create web-service that work on your C# button request.
Like you have share link request on above question.
When php web-service found request parameter and check with database than it's direct start the session.
Hope this will help you.

Answer (score -1):

Yes it's possible but I would advise against this as it presents a security risk.  Based on the on the URL you posted, you would be storing and then passing the username and password to the website.

Is username and password the only authentication scheme you can use?

Comment: so, any idea How to do it ?